# Joomla Plugin: "Another plugin is already using the named folder"

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions

I am just developing my first Joomla plugin.

Installing for the first time works fine, but re-installing (plugin already installed, just like updating it) throws the following warning:

> Extension Install: Another plugin is already using the named folder
>   . Are you trying to install the same extension again?

This doesn't occur when reinstalling plugins I downloaded from the Joomla Extension Repository.
So I must have a problem within the plugins XML file or with my file or folder naming. Maybe case sensitivity...

Can someone help me?

Comment: r u remove first one before installing agian ?

Comment: No I just re-install, as if I'm updating the plugin to a higher version.

Comment: instead of reinstalling why don't you update it using joomla core functionality

Comment: as it is custom plugin u can make changes in ur file directly or if u want to reinstall u need to remove first one otherwise u need to change names in xml ,folder also

Comment: reading this article http://www.atlanticintelligence.net/forum-127/simplecaddy-2-0-5/15844-package-install-uninstall-problems-w-fix you might want to check if all names follow the required rules for naming.

Comment: Why I don't update via Joomla Core or remove before updating:
I want my extension to be cleanly developed, according to Joomla's guidelines. Maybe I want to publish it to Joomla's extension repository at some later point... Since other extensions can be reinstalled without problems, there must be some inconsistency in my files....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per https://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_file, you need to specify `method="Upgrade"` in the primary tag in your xml manifest file to allow an install to overwrite an existing folder as in the following example:

```
<extension version="3.0" type="plugin" group="system" method="upgrade">
```